# glamour and decadence

Tags: vocabulary

What does *glamour* and *decadence* imply here? One of them has a positive connotation, while the other has a negative connotation.

Viva La Juicy by Juicy Couture. She is couture all the way. Spinning an addictive web of glamour and decadence at the center of her golden world. For her, all that glitters is gold. Her fragrance, Viva la Juicy Gold Couture.

Reference: https://www.mrfragrancesllc.com/women/463-417-viva-la-juicy-gold-couture-34-oz-edp-spray-719346186551.html

Comment: What are the definitions of those two words?

Comment: I know the definition of these words, what struck me as odd was the fact that these two words, having opposing connotations, are used together.

Answer (score 1):

In fashion, which is the context of your quotation, *decadence* has a connotation that’s really positive:

> 1 : characterized by or appealing to self-indulgence

> a rich and decadent dessert

> the hotel's decadent luxury

> 2 : marked by decay or decline

> an increasingly decadent society

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/decadent

Comment: MW defines it as self-indulgence. Does self-indulgence have a positive connotation in English?

Comment: It has a connotation of pleasure that’s just a little naughty, perhaps, and thus of sexiness, which is what the fashion appeal is all about, whether it’s the food, the very elegant surroundings, or the clothing.